# How to add dynamic items in an empty dynamic list when a button is clicked in flutter?

Tags: list, flutter

### SITUATION

I have a dynamic empty list of type `shoe` as below

```
class Shoe {
  String brand;
  int quantity;
  String image;
  Color productColor;
  int indexNumber;
  
  Shoe({String b, int q, String i, Color c, int iN}) {
    brand = b;
    quantity = q;
    image = i;
    productColor = c;
    indexNumber =iN;
  }
}
```

Dynamic empty list

```
List<Shoe> shoeCartList = [];
```

*How do I add items in the list `shoeCartList` dynamically when a button is pressed?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `add` method on the `shoeCartList` to add items **[in your case `shoe objects`]** to the end of the list.

I added a demo using your code as an example:

```
class ListExample extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Shoe> shoeCartList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 55,
          width: double.infinity,
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () {
              // add items here [ use the .add method on the list]
              shoeCartList.add(
                Shoe(
                  b: VALUE OF b,
                  c: VALUE OF c,
                  i: VALUE OF i,
                  iN: VALUE OF iN,
                  q: VALUE OF q,
                ),
              );
            },
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Add Items',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

List shoeCartList = [];

```
    onPress(){
          shoeCartList.add(Shoe(add your param));
      }
```